# Implementation help on database video matching in OpenCV

Tags: c++, database, opencv, duplicates, workflow

I'm trying to develop a program to match query videos to videos in a database. So something like google image search but for videoclips. I'm using OpenCV for this implementation.

I can succesfully generate feature descriptors for selected frames in de video (which tbh isn't that hard).

I have no clue how I should implement the database part. I was wondering if somebody could give me pointers to what already exists in OpenCV to ease my implementation: What classes to extend, how to structure it, any existing implementations/examples,...?

Basically I would have a set of descriptors from a query clip which I want to compare to a (large) database of precomputed descriptors, and then have some voting algorithm to return a best match.

So i'm **not** asking for which algorithms to use, I just want to know about the best practices in OpenCV to implement such a thing i'm describing.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.8 C++ on a Mac in Xcode, if that somehow matters

**EDIT**
Let me make my question a little bit more specific.
If I use SIFT of SURF detector/descriptor I get a lot of features. Doing this for a bunch of frames of a bunch of videos will result a lot of data.

If I use FlannMatcher (or something in the likes) I have to have everything in memory... but this seems very unreasonable... So somehow there should be a way to implement this using a database. So I'm looking for any hints on how to do this, what kind of database to use...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may cluster the features into fewer classes, and store/search class id before comparing actual features